# Syntax error when using sed to replace line-specific string in parallel: {= s/_1/_2/ =}?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have a directory with files that look like this:

```
id1_1.txt
id1_2.txt
id2_1.txt
id2_2.txt
```

I need to pass these files as a couple (e.g `id1_1.txt` and `id1_2.txt`) to `my_script`.

Here's what I thought would work

```
parallel -j +0 -X python my_script.py -1 {} -2 {= s/_1/_2/ =} -o /output/dir/good /output/dir/bad ::: /my/dir/*_1.txt
```

where `-1` would be files ending in `_1.txt` and `-2` would be its partner ending `_2.txt`.

`my_script` recognizes the input for option `-1`, but not the input for option `-2`. Clearly, it's only looking for the initial part of option `-2`:

```
 No such file or directory: '{='
```

I tried adding quotes, but still get the same error.

Parallel version:

```
$ parallel --version
GNU parallel 20120522
Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.

Web site: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

When using GNU Parallel for a publication please cite:

O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool,
;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show what `parallel --version` says?

Comment: It looks like the substitution syntax (which uses Perl, not Sed, under the hood) was added in 20140722. See the [GNU parallel - NEWS](https://gitlab.com/GNU/Parallel/blob/master/NEWS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As steeldriver pointed out, the version of parallel that I had installed pre-dated the synatx I was using ([GNU parallel - NEWS](https://gitlab.com/GNU/Parallel/blob/master/NEWS)).

As a side note, the [GNU parallel index](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/) lists the OLDEST versions at the top and the newest at the bottom. When I downloaded parallel on my new workspace, I didn't pay attention to this and grabbed the top .tar thinking it was the newest version.